# CROS Origin API Call issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, plugins

I host my MVC API in server 'A'.

I tried to call API using jquery ajax call from native server (server 'A'). it's working fine as expected.

But, when tried to call API from server 'B'. I got an error.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

My ajax call like below

```
$.ajax({
    url: Url,
    type: "GET",
    data: Data,
    contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log("Exception in ajaxRequest - " + xhr.status + ' - ' + thrownError);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        ResultData = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's expected. It's called cross-domain calls and it's almost impossible to achieve, unless the server you're calling explicitely allows it.

Comment: P.S. `async: false` is a big no no. Not only it's a bad practice but it's now officially deprecated.

Comment: how to make explicitly allow API server ?

Comment: The server has to allow it. If you're trying to make a direct call to `somewebsite.com` from the browser, then `somewebsite.com` has to explicitely allow it. There are two solutions for this : 1) Call the admins of the site and ask them to allow cross-domain, but it's unlikely to happen. 2) Make the call from your server, and then send the response back to the browser.

Comment: And don't forget to remove `async: false`.

Comment: Are you in control of 'server A'? Or is it managed by a service?

Comment: Yes i am having control of server 'A' . I can able to modify .kindly guide me to do needful

Comment: I have created the Server 'A'. that is MVC API . that don't have any restricted information. so, i can able to make as open environment

Comment: may be access control header help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: my bad luck :( i can understand the article. but, not able to get any further details to do. i may not stuff that much